# When Deleting Files from External Drive I am Constantly Being Prompted for Assurance

Tags: macos, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, trash

I have the new Mac Pro with 10.9.3. The Home Folder is on a separate drive using magnetic links. Lately things have not been running normally. One of the main issues is that every time I want to delete something I get this message:

> Are you sure you want to delete "filename"? This item will be deleted immediately. You can't undo this action.
>
> [image: Are you sure you want to delete "filename"? This item will be deleted immediately. You can't undo this action.]

It is driving me up a wall. I have read somewhere that you can change a configuration file so that the external hard drive tells OS X that it is a hard drive vs something more mobile like a USB stick and the trash function works like it does on the boot drive (delete sends to trash, and emptying the trash get your prompt like above).

This is what my boot drive looks like:

[image: Boot drive home folder]

Almost all of the files are symbolic links to the RAID drive. In the library the Mobile Sync and Mail's V2 are also linked. This have worked well for 2-3 years, but lately I have been having these problems.

```
BB:~ n3wst6rtpro$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         499.4 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           *499.1 GB   disk1
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                 Apple_RAID                         4.0 TB     disk2s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk2s3
/dev/disk3
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk3
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS 5Big_Boot               650.3 GB   disk3s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS 5Big_LTStore            1.3 TB     disk3s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS 5Big_TM                 2.0 TB     disk3s4
/dev/disk4
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk4
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk4s1
   2:                 Apple_RAID                         4.0 TB     disk4s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk4s3
/dev/disk5
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk5
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk5s1
   2:                 Apple_RAID                         4.0 TB     disk5s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk5s3
/dev/disk6
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk6
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk6s1
   2:                 Apple_RAID                         4.0 TB     disk6s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk6s3
/dev/disk7
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS 5Big_D2DStore          *4.0 TB     disk7
```

And here is some helpful info perhaps about the permissions on that drive:

```
BB:5Big_D2DStore 1 n3wst6rtpro$ ls -alFe
total 656
drwxrwxr-x@ 18 root  wheel     680 Jun 23 15:19 ./
0: group:admin allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextat tr,writeextattr,readsecurity
drwxrwxrwt@ 10 root  admin     340 Jun 29 09:57 ../
0: group:everyone deny add_file,add_subdirectory,directory_inherit,only_inherit
-rw-rw-r--@  1 root  wheel   12292 Jun 29 05:15 .DS_Store
0: group:admin allow read,write,append,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
d--x--x--x   8 root  wheel     272 Jun 29 09:57 .DocumentRevisions-V100/
drwxrwxr-x+  9 root  wheel     306 Jun 21 10:01 .DocumentRevisions-V100-bad-1/
0: group:admin allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextat tr,writeextattr,readsecurity
drwxrwxr-x+  2 root  wheel      68 Mar 22 12:41 .IABootFiles/
0: group:admin allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextat tr,writeextattr,readsecurity
-rw-rw-r--+  1 root  wheel     305 Mar 22 13:30 .IAProductInfo
0: group:admin allow read,write,append,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
drwxrwxr-x+  5 root  wheel     170 Apr  5 05:05 .Spotlight-V100/
0: group:admin allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextat tr,writeextattr,readsecurity
drwxrwxr-x@  5 root  wheel     170 Mar 21 19:25 .TemporaryItems/
0: group:admin allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextat tr,writeextattr,readsecurity
d-wx-wx-wT   3 root  wheel     102 Jun 16 06:31 .Trashes/
-rw-rw-r--@  1 root  wheel  302570 Apr  5 05:22 .VolumeIcon.icns
0: group:admin allow read,write,append,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
-rw-rw-r--@  1 root  wheel     322 Mar 30 19:07 .apdisk
0: group:admin allow read,write,append,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
-rw-rw-r--+  1 root  wheel       0 Mar 22 11:09 .com.apple.timemachine.supported
0: group:admin allow read,write,append,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
drwxrwxr-x+ 42 root  wheel    1428 Jun 29 09:56 .fseventsd/
0: group:admin allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextat tr,writeextattr,readsecurity
drwxrwxr-x+  6 root  wheel     204 Jun 24 03:38 Users/
0: group:admin allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextat tr,writeextattr,readsecurity
drwxrwxr-x+  8 root  wheel     272 Jun 15 06:29 _Archived Items/
0: group:admin allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextat tr,writeextattr,readsecurity
```

Comment: If I had 4 more reputation points I could mark this as solved and close it out.

Comment: Answering your own questions after you solved ot showing how is not only allowed, but encouraged.

Comment: I would have but, since I am new to the site there are restrictions.

Comment: I think you just have to wait a little longer.

Answer (score 3):

After a ton of changing permissions, it was noticed that I had two .Trash and .Trashes folders in my Home folder as you can see above.

`sudo rm -r ~/.Trash`, `sudo rm -r ~/.Trashes` and then a restart fixed my system and it is running clean as a whistle.

Comment: In a circular dance that I do from time to time. I have fixed one problem and created another. I know this will make some people's nose cringe, but What are the "normal" permissions for different directories and files? Is the only real place to check in the .BOM files where the receipt is or is there a published standard somewhere and is considered best practice?